# How to navigate one to another navigation controller iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

My scenario I have three view controller A, B and C. A is the root view controller, In A button click to navigate B view controller and In side B view controller button click to navigate C view controller. It is working fine by below code.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstview") as? ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

But, Each view controller I want to show separate navigation bar or navigation controller. If i set bar it is not covering status bar but if I embed navigation controller it showing proper bar in story board but output showing previous view controller bar and back button. Here, problem is A view controller I made transparent but B and C also showing transparent. I want to show separate navigation bar in B and C.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpMd2.png)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have embedded navigation controller on root view controller and when you move from one Vc to another the navigation bar is the same as root view controller with a back button and it is obvious because you have embedded the navigation controller in root view controller.

one thing you can do is instead of making a segue like this:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

you can try;

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

this code present your view controller B and C without the navigation controller

Comment: please do this things in main thread
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 //whatever you want to do in interface
                }

Comment: In Swift Tasks can be performed synchronously or asynchronously.

    Synchronous function returns the control on the current queue only after task is finished. It blocks the queue and waits until the task is finished.

    Asynchronous function returns control on the current queue right after task has been sent to be performed on the different queue. It doesn't wait until the task is finished. It doesn't block the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify/update the title of the navigation bar using

```
self.navigationItem.title = "your_title"
```

If you want to add some fancy view to the navigation bar you can use this

```
func updateTitle(_ title: String?) {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 400))
    label.text = title
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.textColor = .white
    self.navigationItem.title = ""
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label
}
```

Hope this helps